# How to rename text files in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-processing

I have 100 text files and i would like to rename files inorder

```
my text files looks like this 

note 1.txt, note 6.txt,note 15.txt,note 24.txt
```

```
i need to be renamed as note 1.txt,note 2.txt,note 3.txt,.....
```

```
i'm facing an issue like this 

Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'note 1.txt' -> 'note 6.txt'

it should come in order  of 1,2,3....
```

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/rename-multiple-files-using-python/

Comment: What code have to tried to rename the files? @Krishna

Comment: @MonisMajeed i used the same code

Comment: ```code
 snames=glob("Note *.txt")


for file in snames:
    s_num=os.path.splitext(file)[0].split()[1]
    lst_num=[1,6,8,12,25,28,41,47,71,72,84,86,90,,94,97]
    if int(s_num) in lst_num:
        for i in lst_num:
            indx=lst_num.index(i)+1
            print(indx)
            dst="Note "+str(i)+".txt"
            src=file
            os.rename(src,dst) 
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `os` and `re` module

**Ex:**

```
import os
import re
path = "Your Path"

for num, file in enumerate(sorted(os.listdir(path), key=lambda x: int(re.search(r"(\d+)", x).group(1))), 1):
    if not re.search(r"\b{}\.txt".format(num), file):
        print("Rename", file, num)
        os.rename(os.path.join(path, file), os.path.join(path, re.sub(r"\d+", str(num), file)))
    else:
        print("Good", file, num)
```